# Can I define static fields in racket classes?

Tags: oop, racket

I couldn't find a way to define a static field in racket. By static, I mean a field that belongs to the entire class and not to an instance.

```
(define counter% (class object%  
  (field (current-count 0))
  (super-new)

  (define/public (get-count)
    current-count)

  (define/public (next) 
    (set! current-count (+ current-count 1))
    (set! total (+ total 1))
    (list current-count total))))

(define c1 (new counter%))
(define c2 (new counter%))

(send c1 next)
(send c1 next)
(send c1 next)
(send c2 next)
```

So `total` in this example should be a static field and the output should be:

```
'(1 1)
'(2 2)
'(3 3)
'(1 4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this solution?

```
#lang racket

(define counter%
  (let ([total 0])
    (class object%  
      (field (current-count 0))
      (super-new)

      (define/public (get-count)
        current-count)

      (define/public (next) 
        (set! current-count (+ current-count 1))
        (set! total (+ total 1))
        (list current-count total)))))

(define c1 (new counter%))
(define c2 (new counter%))

(send c1 next)
(send c1 next)
(send c1 next)
(send c2 next)
```

Comment: Yep it does what I want. I also found a way to do this by defining a global variable `(define total 0)` outside a class but I suppose your way is better.

Comment: Both techniques work, but making `total` local signals to a reader of the code, that `total` is used by that class only.

Comment: A third alternative is to keep the variable within the module and not export it.